# Multiplying each line of a file by minus one

Tags: bash, awk, sed

If I have a simple text file, containing numbers of all negative value, how do I make all of those values positive?

So as an example, if test.txt has the following values:

```
-4
-5
-6
```

How do I make it so that the values are positive?

```
4
5
6
```

Comment: What if a line contains a positive number? Or zero? What if it contains something that's not a number?

Comment: @ClickRick - The file does not contain anything that is not a negative number.

Comment: Ed Morton's answer is the best since no computation is needed.

Comment: You're getting a lot of answers that use shell loops - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all, of the reasons not to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tr -d '-' < file
```

......................

Answer (score 2):

So one of the MATHs rule if we multiply -1 with any number it will be changed to positive number of it's own(in case it is already negative), so similarly we could do it here as follows.

```
awk '{$0=$0 * -1} 1' Input_file
```

Hope this helps you.

So let's say your Input_fie has negative and positives both the values as follows.

```
cat file1
-4
-5
-6
7
```

Then following code we could use to avoid making everything negative(specially those which values are already positive).

```
awk '{$0=$0<0?$0 * -1:$0} 1'  Input_file
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Creative, this works. Thank you!

Comment: doesn't make sense to force awk to resplit every line vs just `print $0 * -1`.

Comment: Then maybe `awk '{$1*=-1}1' input_file`

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to convert to positive only when the number is negative:

```
while read -r number; do
   [[ number -lt 0 ]] && number=$((-1 * number))
   echo $number
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Using the shell's `while read` to loop over the lines in a file is frequently an antipattern. A simple Awk or Perl script would be my solution, and probably an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @tripleee: I agree with you.  Thanks to SO, I am learning the intricacies of bash.  I thought I was strong in bash.  But after spending some quality time on this site, boy, I know how far I was from being strong!  A number of years ago, I picked Perl over awk and for small and throw-away code, I tend to use pure bash.

Comment: I've gravitated the other way, swinging back from Perl to Awk for small throw-away code (and generally now to Python for anything where I would still have used Perl). Anyway, welcome to the site, and feel free to check out the [bash chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash) and/or the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info)!

Answer (score -1):

It seems you don’t want to do any math, but simply remove all minus signs. In this case,

```
while read line; do echo ${line//-/}; done <test.txt
```

does the job without invoking external programs. It works also in the case that there is more than one number per line.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I make the following assumptions:

- you actually want the mathematical opposite of the number in the file

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a
do
    echo -1*$a | bc
done <test.txt
```